# FFmpeg: Extract Subtitles for Selected Files Using Input Name for Output in Caja Script?

Tags: scripts, video, ffmpeg, subtitle, caja

OK, I know the command for extracting subtitles, and I know how to make Caja scripts (which are great because I can assign keyboard shortcuts to them), but what I'd like to know is what command to add to a script so that when run it will extract the subs from any MKV no matter the name, and preferably grab that name and use it for the output SRT file.

Currently I use this command via a terminal, after renaming a copy of the video to **movie.mkv**, with the extracted subs ending up in **movie.srt** (using **s:0** since usually the English subs are the first subtitle track):

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mkv -vn -an -codec:s:0 srt movie.srt
```

And putting it in a Caja script works great - as long as I'm running it on **movie.mkv**, obviously. While executing the script via keyboard shortcut makes it a tad faster than opening a terminal and running that command (which I can do quickly via a **subs** alias), what I'd really like to be able to do is run that on the selected MKV video, regardless of its name (and which may contain spaces), and preferably have that name given to the output **.srt** file (but I'd be happy with the output being **movie.srt** - it's not having to rename a video, or copy of it, that is my main objective). And while being able to do this on multiple files at once would be a bonus, having to do it individually wouldn't be an issue.

I've tried various approaches I've seen online (mostly in regards to batch processing) using wildcards and whatnot, but I'm out of my depth, so need your expertise on this! Cheers, and many thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**: I've managed to nut out a command which extracts the subs from the selected file (regardless of name) to subs.srt:

```
ffmpeg -i "$1" -vn -an -codec:s:0 srt subs.srt
```

... so if anyone knows how to get it to grab the name from the file and pass it along to the .srt file, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

OMG, I should have just kept tinkering, as I came up with the solution not long after, haha. But at least this is here now for anyone else who's searching for this answer. So the correct code to extract subs from the selected video file and give the **.srt** file the name of the source file is:

```
ffmpeg -i "$1" -vn -an -codec:s:0 srt "${1%.mkv}.srt"
```

And if you're wanting to create a script to **extract the forced subs** (for non-English parts only), since that's usually the 2nd subtitle track use this instead:

```
ffmpeg -i "$1" -vn -an -codec:s:1 srt "${1%.mkv}.srt"
```

Or, since I've had varied success with that last one, use:

```
mkvextract tracks "$1" 2:"${1%.mkv}.srt"
```

And because the track # of the forced subs can vary, you can do as I've done and create multiple scripts - for example calling the one above **Extract Subtitles Track 2**, and another with **3:** instead of **2:** called **Extract Subtitles Track 3** with the code:

```
mkvextract tracks "$1" 3:"${1%.mkv}.srt"
```

Then you can assign keyboard shortcuts by editing the **accels** file, and make it really quick and easy to extract the correct subs (for example, I use Alt+1 to extract the main subs, and Alt+2, Alt+3, Alt+4 and Alt+5 to extract the second, third, fourth and fifth tracks, one of which is bound to be the forced subs).

Hope that's of use to someone out there! Cheers.

(PS: cheers to **andrew.46** for pointing out how to exclude the **.mkv** from ending up in the output's file-name!)

Comment: Does this give an output filename something like 'movie.mkv.srt'? If so perhaps: `ffmpeg -i "$1" -vn -an -codec:s:0 srt "${1%.mkv}.srt"`

Comment: Andrew, it gives the full name of the source video, including the .mkv extension, before the .srt. I'm not really worried about it including the ".mkv" in the file name - I just want the subtitle file to end up next to the source video - but if you know the way to get it to exclude that when naming, the .srt file, feel free to let me know!

Comment: My suggestion is in the comment above yours :)

Comment: Andrew, cheers! While having the **.mkv** in there really wouldn't bug me at all (I actually didn't even notice till you asked!), I know it would bug others, so thanks for that - I'll amend my answer with your info. You learn something new every day!